# How to resolve this linking error

Tags: c++, dynamic-linking

I have a class A, that is an abstract base class.(C++). Now, I have two classes B and C which inherit from A;

I have a virtual destructor in A;
The constructor in class A is protected.
Now, in the constructors of B and C, I have included a call to A's constructor.

```
B::B():A()
{
//do something
}
```

similarly for C

```
C::C():A()
{
//do something
}
```

Now, while compiling I'm getting linking errors.

```
    B.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: __
thiscall A::A(void)" (??0A) referenced in function "protected: __thiscall B::B(void)" (??0B)

    C.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected:
__thiscall A::A(void)" (??0A@XZ)
      Error.
```

Please suggest how to resolve this.

Thanks,
Karhtik.

Comment: Post the full code. There's bound to be a bug in the code you're *not* showing us.

Comment: I cannot:(.Im not allowed to.

Comment: Try to construct a minimal example that reproduces your problem.  Otherwise there's no real question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, there's really no need to "call" the base class constructor explicitly. The default constructor of the base class will be called for you automatically.

Secondly, as @DeadMG already noted, the error you are getting suggests that you explicitly declared the `A::A()` constructor, but forgot to define it.

Answer (score 0):

This suggests that you never defined the default constructor of A when you declared it.

Comment: @user815961: If it was "in place", you wouldn't be getting these linker errors. No, the constructor definition is not "in place" (whatever you mean by that "in place")

Comment: Hi all, actually, the abstract base class (A) has a constructor. And removing it from that abstract base class and all its child's (B & C) is resolving the issue.

Is it that an abstract base class cannot have a constructor?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057221/what-are-practical-uses-of-a-protected-constructor